# php retriving data using file_get_contents

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I am trying to retrieve a JSON response from the following [link](http://demo.openalpr.com:8010/status?nonce=772493352) using `file_get_contents()` but I can't seem to get the response. However when I type the link into my browser I get a response.

How can I read the response in my PHP? I already tried using

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents("http://demo.openalpr.com:8010/status?nonce=772493352");
?>
```

whit no success.

Comment: Please post the exact error message you get, and include any relevant server PHP logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you don't have the [allow_url_fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php) setting activated, thus remote URL's are not loadable by your PHP scripts.

Check your `php.ini` file and set this to `On`.